# Beginner Lua, Array

Tags: lua

What is the purpose of Line 2 In my code?

```
local table = {["First"] = 1, ["Second"] = 2, ["Third"] = 3}

for key, value in pairs(table) do
    print(key)
end
```

Results-------------

```
First
Second
Third
```

What is the purpose of the line that says, "for key, value in pairs(table) do 
Print(key) ?
I was wondering why it is essential.

Comment: Start reading "Programming in Lua" - best tutorial on Lua

Comment: ... the first edition of which is even available online for free! https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html

Comment: Actually, line 2 is an empty one.

Comment: Array is a foreign concept in Lua. A Lua table is a dictionary in computer science terms. The Lua Reference Manual is a good place to learn, too.

Answer (score 3):

As others have suggested in comments, you should really start by reading *Programming in Lua*. It will explain this and much more and is really a perfect place to start if you want to learn Lua.

### Well then, as for what it does

Given a table like this

```
local tab = {first = 1, second = 2, third = 3}
```

the way you would usually iterate over all the key-value pairs in the table is like this

```
for key, value in pairs(tab) do
  print(key .. ": " .. tostring(value))
end
```

This will loop over the three values in the table `first = 1`, `second = 2`, etc.
For each pair, `key` is set to the table key and `value` to its value. It then executes the code between `do` and `end` with those variables set.

So the example above will print the following:

```
first: 1
second: 2
third: 3
```

### How does it work?

This is a bit more complex; Let's first of all see what `pairs` actually returns:

```
> t = {}
> print(pairs(t))
function: 68f18400    table: 0066b1d8    nil
```

The table it returns as its second argument is the same that we passed in.

The function that's returned by `pairs` is the [`next`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next) function, which, given a table and a key, returns the next key in the table, within an unknown order but without ever repeating keys.

You can easily confirm that on the command line.

```
> print(t)
table: 0066b1d8
> print(next)
function: 68f18400
```

Lua then turns the for loop into something like the following:

```
do
  local f, state, iterator = next, tab, nil -- this is what's returned by pairs
  while true do
    local key, value = f(state, iterator)
    if key == nil then break end
    iterator = key
    print(key, value) -- This is the body of our for loop
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Dark, I appreciate your time for helping me out :)